# Why "delete" operation is considered to be "slow" on a sorted array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, big-o

I am currently studying algorithms and data structures with the help of the famous Stanford course by Tim Roughgarden. In video 13-1 when explaining Balanced Binary Search Trees he compared them to sorted arrays and mentioned that we do not do deletion on sorted array because it is too slow (I believe he meant *"slow in comparison with other operations, that we can run in constant [Select, Min/Max, Pred/Succ], O(log n) [Search, Rank] and O(n) [Output/print] time"*).

I cannot stop thinking about this statement. Namely I cannot wrap my mind around the following:

> Let's say we are given an order statistic or a value of the item we
>   want to delete from a sorted (ascending) array.
>
> We can most certainly find its position in array using Select or
>   Search in constant or O(n) time respectively.
>
> We can then remove this item and iterate over the items to the right
>   of the deleted one, incrementing their indices by one, which will take
>   O(n) time. [this is me (possibly unsuccessfully) trying to describe
>   the 'move each of them 1 position to the left' operation]
>
> The whole operation will take linear time - O(n) - in the worst case
>   scenario.

**Key question** - Am I thinking in a wrong way? If not, why is it considered slow and undesirable?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: deleting from an array is slow because you have to move all elements after it one position to the left, so that you can cover the hole you created.

Whether `O(n)` is considered slow depends on the situation. Deleting from an array is most likely part of a larger, more complex algorithm, e.g. inside a loop. This then would add a factor of `n` to your final complexity, which is usually bad. Using a tree would only add a factor of `log n`, and `O(n log n)` is *much* better than `O(n^2)` (asymptotically).

Comment: Thank you! But is linear time considered slow then?

Comment: @IdoVanOrell it is slow if you have like a billion of items. It is slow if it takes more time than the user is prepared to spend on it.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is relative to the specific data structure which is being used to hold the sorted values: A sorted array.  This specific data structure would be selected for simplicity, for efficient storage, and for quick searches, but is slow for adding and removing elements from the data structure.

Other data structures which hold sorted values may be selected.  For example, a binary tree, or a balanced binary tree, or a trie.  Each has different characteristics in terms of operation performance and storage efficiency, and would be selected based on the intended usage.

A sorted array is slow for additions and removals because, on average, these operations require shifting half of the array to make room for a new element (or, respectively, to fill in an emptied cell).

However, on many architectures, the simplicity of the data structure and the speed of shifting means that the data structure is fine for "small" data sets.

Comment: "We do not do deletion on sorted array" is badly stated.  Better: "Do not choose sorted array as the implementation data structure if too many deletions are to be performed".  The focus should be on what data structure to use, not whether or not to perform deletions.